# Group only unbroken sequence in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of items that are listed by year. For example

```
{ id: 1, Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 1998 }
{ id: 2, Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 1999 }
{ id: 3, Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 2001 }
{ id: 4, Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 2002 }
```

I want to group the data by make, name, engine size, etc... and I want to $push the years and id into a "years" element. I have that working fine, but in the above data, you'll notice that year: 2000 is missing.

How can I aggregate these documents in MongoDB so that I end up with two results: One for [1998, 1999] and one for [2001, 2002]? I can easily put a check value to detect a gap in the sequence and handle it in my application, but it seems like it might be cleaner to get it from the DB.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be cleaner to do this in the application - trust me!

Comment: The thing is, I don't really want to decode, modify, and re-encode the JSON being passed to the view of my app (I'm using PHP). And I don't want to do this in the view itself. So it seemed better to come from the DB.

Comment: not sure why people are downvoting this - you can do this in aggregation pipeline - you definitely don't need mapReduce for it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with MapReduce instead.

I came up with the idea that if I could "select" a new sequential number (0, 1, 2, 3, etc against each document), and subtract it from the year, it would give me a check value. For example:

```
seq: 1, year: 1998, check(year-seq): 1997
seq: 2, year: 1999, check(year-seq): 1997
seq: 3, year: 2001, check(year-seq): 1998
seq: 4, year: 2002, check(year-seq): 1998
```

Now I can group by the check value. But how to generate this check value? Since it appears that MongoDB aggregation doesn't know about other documents, and doesn't allow javascript, it cannot create the incrementing sequence on a per-query basis. Therefore I worked out how MapReduce works and produced the following:

```
db.cars.insert({Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 1998 })
db.cars.insert({Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 1999 })
db.cars.insert({Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 2001 })
db.cars.insert({Make: "Audi", name: "A3", year: 2002 })

db.cars.mapReduce(
    // map function
    function() {

        check = this.year - sequence;

        key = {
            make: this.Make,
            name: this.name,
            check: check,
        }

        value = { _id: this._id, year: this.year };
        emit(key, value);

        sequence++;

    }
    // end of map
    ,
    // reduce
    function(key, values) {
        var result = {individual_models: [] };
        values.forEach(function(v) {
            result.individual_models.push({ _id: v._id, year: v.year});
        });
        return result;
    }
    // end reduce
    ,
    {
        out: { inline: 1 },
        scope: { "sequence": 0},
    }
)
```

This gives my result:

```
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "make" : "Audi",
                                "name" : "A3",
                                "check" : 1998
                        },
                        "value" : {
                                "individual_models" : [
                                        {
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55115957f8198b539c3c41e4"),
                                                "year" : 1998
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("5511595df8198b539c3c41e5"),
                                                "year" : 1999
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "make" : "Audi",
                                "name" : "A3",
                                "check" : 1999
                        },
                        "value" : {
                                "individual_models" : [
                                        {
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55115961f8198b539c3c41e6"),
                                                "year" : 2001
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("55115962f8198b539c3c41e7"),
                                                "year" : 2002
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 1,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 4,
                "emit" : 4,
                "reduce" : 2,
                "output" : 2
        },
        "ok" : 1,
}
```

Probably needs more testing to ensure it'll work for my whole record set but it seems to be what I wanted.